# How to draw a boxplot from multi-column grouped frequency in R?

Tags: r, frequency, boxplot

I have a large dataset that looks like similar to this,

```
   StudentID SectorID ClassID
1          A   Team_1 Class_1
2          A   Team_1 Class_1
3          B   Team_1 Class_1
4          B   Team_2 Class_1
5          B   Team_2 Class_1
6          A   Team_2 Class_1
7          A   Team_3 Class_1
8          C   Team_3 Class_2
9          C   Team_3 Class_2
10         C   Team_3 Class_2
11         C   Team_3 Class_2
12         C   Team_1 Class_2
13         D   Team_1 Class_2
14         D   Team_1 Class_2
```

This could be generated by,

```
stg <- data.frame(StudentID = c( rep("A", 2), rep("B", 3), rep("A", 2), rep("C", 5), rep("D", 2)  ),
                  SectorID  = c(rep("Team_1", 3), rep("Team_2", 3), rep("Team_3", 5), rep("Team_1", 3)),               
                  ClassID     = c(rep("Class_1", 7), rep("Class_2", 7) )            
)
```

Then, managed to find frequency of StudentID grouped by each Sector and then Class.

```
stg.a <- aggregate(stg$StudentID, by =  list(SectorID = stg$SectorID, ClassID = stg$ClassID), count )
```

But here count returns some sort of *complex list.* And if you examine stg.a, you will strange or apparently misleading output. So, I converted it to a matrix,

```
stg.a.f <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(stg.a))
```

and that looks like this,

```
  SectorID ClassID  x.x x.freq
1   Team_1 Class_1 1, 2   2, 1
2   Team_2 Class_1 1, 2   1, 2
3   Team_3 Class_1    1      1
4   Team_1 Class_2 3, 4   1, 2
5   Team_3 Class_2    3      4
```

The first lines reads,
In Team_1, in Class_1 student number 1 (ID: A), appeared 2 times,
                      student numner 2 (ID: B), appeared 1 time.

Now, I want to show this as plots, mainly boxplot, say on Y-axis, I want to see the frequency (if possible separated by color from Student_ID (x.x) ) and then grouped by some factors (e.g., Team, Class)

Answer (score 0):

I see the attempt to find frequency as complex without desired results. I recommend creating a simple data.frame by finding combined items and recording their frequencies. This can be done using the `table` function as follows:

```
stg.a <- as.data.frame(table(stg$StudentID, stg$SectorID, stg$ClassID))
names(stg.a)<-c(colnames(stg), 'Freq')
```

There are possible combinations with zero values. Depending on the desired analysis, you may or may not have value for keeping or removing them from the set. If removing the zero values is the best option then run command

```
stg.a<-stg.a[which(stg.a$Freq>0),]
```

This should provide an easier platform to build your graphs.

Let me know if you need help with plots. I would ask for more clarity than provided in OP on what you are trying to show and how.

Comment: 1) Thanks a million @sfyn for your time. Your help certainly solves the basic problem I was trying to solve. However, in this solution, I could not apply (yet) facets to show different grouping.  << Still I am trying

    2) In my earlier approach to solve the problem: it contains StudentID information in the data, probably giving us a possibility to color each point as per StudentID. I guess, that would be interesting to see. << I hit the wall as earlier.